# Refreshed Cache in Cache Management, lost access to front and backend, Magento 1.9.1 :(

Tags: magento-1.9, error, cache, fatal-error, ce-1.9.1.0

I refreshed cache in Cache Management and I lost access to both front and backend.
This is a basically a fresh install of Magento1.9.1.

Here's the error message:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/__default.php on line 21022
```

And the line in question:

```
> protected function _checkCookieStore($type)
>     {
>          //This is the line in question
>         if (!$this->getCookie()->get()) {
>             return $this;
>         }
```

I'm a programing newbie basically learning as I go atm so I have no idea whats happening.
Thanks in advance!!
-B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it in following way

- I removed `magento/var/cache/`
- I also disabled the compiler for good measure

Now I can access both front and backend again!